# How to make flex child height to wrap content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I basically want is to make each child element's height to wrap its content.

Here is my code:

```
<style>

.parent{
        display: flex;
    }

.child{

    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: green;
    height: auto;
}   

</style>

<div class="parent">

    <div class="child">child1</div>
    <div class="child">child2</div>
    <div class="child">child3</div>
    <div class="child" style="height:50px">child1</div>

</div>
```

Output:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: `align-content:flex-start` worked for me to reset the default `stretch`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to set  [`align-items: flex-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) on parent element because default value is `stretch`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child1</div>
  <div class="child">child2</div>
  <div class="child">child3</div>
  <div class="child" style="height:50px">child1</div>
</div>
```